# How do I put Checkboxes in certain rows based on rows having imported data?

Tags: google-sheets

I am building a series of sheets with multiple tabs. Based on the imported data a tab could have 30 rows in one week and 35 in another week. I want to have checkboxes at the beginning of each row so I can select rows to be imported into another sheet based on boxes being checked or not checked. Is this possible or do I just need to add checkboxes to column A and just deal with them going into rows with nothing left in the column?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Is the sheet being filled by a form?

Comment: A simple trick might be to have the checkboxes for every row, but if the rest of the row was blank, use a conditional formatting rule to change the font colour of the checkboxes to white, to make those boxes invisible.  Just a cosmetic enhancement...

Comment: 1. Use an empty column as your "check" column, just write an "X" or some character to "check" the row.
2. On your other sheet use a VLOOKUP for the "X" character so it will bring in the matching rows.

Comment: @RaulMarquez I am importing the Data from a table on a website and I am using the sheet as data for the rest of the sheets.

Comment: @kirkg13 I don't see an option change the color of the boxes

Comment: The option is the "font" colour, not the "fill" colour.  Changing the font colour of a cell with a checkbox to white, with a white background, would make it appear invisible.  If you then click on it, I think it warns you, since you can't see it.  You would only set the font colour to white in the conditional formatting rule, if the row is otherwise blank.

Answer (score 0):

I was initially putting the checkboxes on the sheets that I was making with the Imported Datasheet. This was giving me checkboxes that went on infinitely after I had imported 20 - 30 items in a query. My solution was to put the checkboxes on the first sheet (nobody sees it but me) and then the only checkboxes on the query sheet were attached to the lines of data.